# Facebook manual authentication flow with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm trying to manually implement an authentication flow via FB oauth.
Here I call the authorization dialog:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
response_type=code
&scope=user_about_me
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback
&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>Login FB</a>
```

Then it redirects back to my app server:

```
http://localhost:3000/login/callback?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

That calls the FB `API graph` to exchange the code for an access token

```
function exchangeCodeForAccessToken(code) {
    const options = {
      hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
      path: 'v2.11/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_secret=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&code=' + code,
      method: 'GET'
    };
    const req = https.request(options, (res2) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${res2.statusCode}`);
      res2.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log(d);
      });
    });
    req.end();
  }
```

But here I always get a 400 with no other indication. No matter what I change. Any advice?

Thank you

edit. As suggested by CBroe I tried to execute the very same request from browser right after the node request (same url, same querystring, same code): 
node -> 400
browser -> 200 + AccessToken

Comment: For starters, you could try what the result is when you call that same URL directly in your browser ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply put protocol 'https' in the `host` property.